# From dictionary of dataframes, how to get specific row based one column being closest to value

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dictionaries of dataframes. The keys are the same across all three dictionaries, and the dataframes all have the same format.

example:

```
Dictionary 1      Dictionary 2      Dictionary 3
key   value       key   value       key   value
2     df1         2     df1         2     df1
16    df2         16    df2         16    df2
19    df3         19    df3         19    df3
etc...


Dictionary 1, df1:  
Index        col 1      col 2      col 3
218793       654        87         45
218837       6812       65464      64
218885       6545       8787       72
etc...

Dictionary 2, df1:  
Index        col 1      col 2      col 3
173265       4589       824        15
173380       56756      8567       45
173502       216        64         63
173545       1478       8665       76
etc...

Dictionary 3, df1: 
Index        col 1      col 2      col 3
318793       1125       899        47
318799       6547       83         49
318824       6          1158       64
318863       9963       224        69
etc...
```

For each row in each dataframe in Dictionary 1, I want to add this row plus one each from the other respective dataframes/dictionaries that have the closest value for col 3 into a new dataframe.

I've tried looping through the first dictionary using argsort to find the nearest values but I'm no expert and can't figure it out.

This is my current attempt:

```py
def matches(dict1, dict2, dict3)
   ans = pd.DataFrame()
   for k, v in dict1.items():
      for i in range(v):
      value = dict1[k].iloc[i,3] #this should be the col3 value
      ans.append(v)  # this should be each row in each df in dict1
      ans.append(dict2[k].iloc[((dict2[k])['col3']-value.abs().argsort()[:1]])
      ans.append(dict3[k].iloc[((dict3[k])['col3']-value.abs().argsort()[:1]])
   return ans
```

I understand how many errors are in this but I have tried so many different ways and I am pulling at straws!

I want to output the following:

```
index   col 1       col 2       col 3
1       654         87          45       (from dict1, df1, row 1)
2       56756       8567        45       (from dict2, df1, row 2)
3       1125        899         47       (from dict3, df1, row 1)
4       6812        65464       64       (from dict1, df1, row 2)
5       216         64          63       (from dict2, df1, row 3)
6       6           1158        64       (from dict3, df1, row 3)
...
9652    4546        45454       1564     (from dict1, df62, row 56)
9653    4225        65          1564     (from dict2, df62, row 61)
9654    3326        272         1570     (from dict3, df62, row 49)
etc...
```

I get no end of errors, little point putting them here.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
ans = pd.Dataframe()

for k,v in dict1.items():
    for i in v.col3:
        dict1_temp = (dict1[k].iloc[(dict1[k]['col3']-i)).abs().argsort()[:1]])
        dict2_temp = (dict2[k].iloc[(dict2[k]['col3']-i)).abs().argsort()[:1]])
        dict3_temp = (dict3[k].iloc[(dict3[k]['col3']-i)).abs().argsort()[:1]])

        ans = ans.append(temp1)
        ans = ans.append(temp2)
        ans = ans.append(temp3)

    return ans
```

If anyone has a more efficient way of doing it I would be grateful to hear it.